# How to search on multiple fields in URI Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to perform an AND operation in ElasticSearch using the URI Search (q=). How do I do it?

If I have document like:
[{ "name":"Test 1", "pub":"2"}, { "name":"Test 2", "pub":"1"}, { "name":"A", "pub":"1"}]

And I would like to query for documents containing with a name containing "Test" AND where pub equals "1". How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: How does your mapping look like? As hinted by the "answer" below, your field needs to be nested and you won't be able to query it using `q=...`, you'll need a full fledge `nested` query for that.

Comment: So for that a need to be able to send the JSOB body on GET to _search, the Query DSL?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your document looks like this:

```
{
    "my_field": [
        { "name":"Test 1", "pub":"2"}, 
        { "name":"Test 2", "pub":"1"}, 
        { "name":"A", "pub":"1"}
    ]
}
```

And the mapping of `my_field` is of type `nested` similar to this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc_type": {
      "properties": {
        "my_field": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": { "type": "string" },
            "pub": {"type": "integer" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can query your index and get the expected documents with the following `nested` query:

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "my_field",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "match": {
                "name": "Test"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "pub": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So if I change so nested type is used instead... will I then be able to do a querystring like: _search?q=this:100 and that:>100
for fields this and that?
Because I thought Elaticsearch was fully searchable on any field combination, doc.myList.this.item:Who AND doc.userData.that.name:Test

Comment: The query string queries support all kinds of queries... except on parent/child docs and nested field (see [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16551))

Answer (score 0):

Actually you'd need nested fields. The following is a good resource.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html