# Elasticsearch URI Search multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I can do a quick [URI search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#search-uri-request) like

```
GET twitter/tweet/_search?q=user:kimchy
```

Can I search multiple fields this way? For example, `user:kimchy AND age:23`?

---

**What I tried 1 (error):**

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/myindex/
curl localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/1 -d '{"a":1,"b":9}'
curl localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/2 -d '{"a":9,"b":9}'
curl localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/3 -d '{"a":9,"b":1}'
```

Say I want just the document `{"a":9, "b":9}`, I tried

```
GET localhost:9200/myindex/_search?q=a:9&b:9
```

but I get error

```
{
    error: {
        root_cause: [{
            type: "illegal_argument_exception",
            reason: "request [/myindex/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [b:9]"
        }],
        type: "illegal_argument_exception",
        reason: "request [/myindex/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [b:9]"
    },
    status: 400
}
```

---

**What I tried 2 (works!):**

```
GET localhost:9200/myindex/_search?q=a:9 AND b:9
```

The spaces are important. Alternatively, use `%20`.

Comment: [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729271/how-to-search-on-multiple-fields-in-uri-search) which requires a more complicated query than mine. I just test for equality.

Comment: Yes, you can. Have you tried?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Try something like this:

```
GET twitter/tweet/_search?q=user:kimchy%20AND%20age:23
```

Note that if you URI decode this, it's equivalent to:

```
GET twitter/tweet/_search?q=user:kimchy AND age:23
```

Note that when you are using this REST endpoint like this, I think you are really taking advantage of something like the [`query_string_query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).  Refer to those docs to get an idea of the extent of the query string language and features available to you.

Comment: It's funny that, when I said in my question `For example, user:kimchy AND age:23` in my question, I was not literally talking about this syntax, which apparently exists and actually works! Thank you so much.

Comment: for me `...%20AND%20...` did not work but `+AND+` worked. [See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39470764/2008111)

Comment: for anyone coming to this post, "AND" has to be capital